# Is the encoding name UTF8 or UTF-8?

Tags: java, httpclient

Some httpclient requires me to give a string charsetµ.

I am wondering whether to give it UTF8 or utf8 or UTF-8?

Especially when calling Charset.forName(enc)

Answer (score 26):

Easier to use [StandardCharsets.UTF_8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html#UTF_8) as it saves you having to deal with UnsupportedEncodingExceptions

Comment: It is right and it equals Charset.forName("UTF-8").

Answer (score 21):

`UTF-8` is the standard one and most people use it.

Here is the list of charsets used in Java:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html

N.B.
If charset factory/singleton classes can take `Enum` as parameter, as well as `String`, `Enum` is, IMO, always a safer and better option.

Comment: Correct. Always use `UTF-8` where you can. A few times you will encounter `utf8` ([Perl being a very scary example](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/blog/1292)), then you should take some time to learn if the designers think their `utf8` is different from the `UTF-8`.

Comment: Good one, I totally forgot about it. It's been a while since I coded something in Perl (and I hope I won't have to do such thing any more xD)

Comment: @Konerak Whoever wrote the perl implementation probably wanted to see whether he could get the number of programs that handle unicode wrongly from 80% into the 99% range. Very scary indeed.

Comment: [Working link that lists encodings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html)

Answer (score 0):

FYI, For Java 7/tomcat 8.5 I am using: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dclient.encoding.override=UTF-8

But for Java 8/tomcat 8.5 I got: 
 java.nio.charset.IllegalCharsetNameException: UTF-8

So I changed to UTF8

Answer (score 0):

The standard name is 'UTF-8'. Source code(I use jdk1.8.0_20) showes more detail:

```
UTF_8 extends Unicode {
    public UTF_8() {
        super("UTF-8", StandardCharsets.aliases_UTF_8); // show other aliases
        // static final String[] aliases_UTF_8 = new String[]{"UTF8", "unicode-1-1-utf-8"};
    }

    public String historicalName() {
        // return old name of UTF-8
        return "UTF8";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Charset charset = Charset.forName("cp1254");
```

This was the utf-8 solution for me. You can use it.